# Setting up and calling a group of celery tasks with individual countdown

Tags: python, django, celery

Using: `Django==2.2.24`, `Python=3.6`, `celery==4.3.0`

**This is what I am currently doing:**

```py
from celery import group

the_group_of_tasks = group(
  some_task.s(an_object.the_data_dict)
  for an_object in AnObject.objects.all()
)
the_group_of_tasks.delay()
```

**What I want to do:**
The `group` documentation: [celery docs link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) 
I would like to spread the `the_group_of_tasks` individual `some_task` calls over some time range.
Best if I can use the `countdown` feature, and spread the tasks over a variable number of seconds (like an hour, 3600 seconds).
The distribution will be done to a random seconds integer between zero and 3600, imagine it can easily be calculated once I have the range.

I think that I can add the `countdown` arg, with a random number generator within my range such that it will be "packaged" and ready to be executed in the `group` with the individual task preparation?

```py
some_task.s(an_object.the_data_dict, countdown=some_generator_call)
```

Would that work?

[In the docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures), it looks like `signature` should support the `countdown`:

```
>>> from celery import signature
>>> signature('tasks.add', args=(2, 2), countdown=10)
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:** 
I tried adding the countdown, like this:

```py
the_group_of_tasks = group(
  some_task.s(an_object.the_data_dict, countdown=10)
  for an_object in AnObject.objects.all()
)
the_group_of_tasks.delay()
```

but seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/application_celery.py", line 85, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'countdown'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that `countdown` was assumed to be an argument to the task, while it was supposed to be an arg to an `apply_async`/`delay` call.

This resolved the issue:

```
the_group_of_tasks = group(
  some_task.signature((an_object.the_data_dict), countdown=10)
  for an_object in AnObject.objects.all()
)
the_group_of_tasks.delay()
```

1. `.s()` was changed to `.signature`
2. Arguments were separated in such way that they are no longer ambiguous

Thank you!